# access user arbitrary folders with chrome localstorage API

Tags: api, filesystems, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm developing an app on Google chrome which could be able to read and write files to arbitrary folders on the user’s hard drive, such as their My Pictures or My Documents folder.

I want my app to has its one folder, like "Users/Username/App", so users could be able to access some of the data, created and edited by the app. How can I do this?

I read the book "Using the HTML5 Filesystem API", so I know it's actually not possible with HTML5 Filesystem API alone. Same thing was possible by opera 11, 12. (see: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/file-i-o-api-for-widgets/). Chorome mediaGalleries API do same things but just for media file but I want to use html, xml and office files

Comment: Your question is very open-ended. From what you write above, the bottom line is that you're trying to write something for Chrome to make it work like a desktop application with desktop app permissions and capabilities.  Simply put, as you've seen everywhere else, that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you've looked at the list of Chrome App APIs. Have you? Among them is the [fileSystem API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html), which is evolving quickly to include directory access.